# Closest_point in Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, point, geometry-generator

I'm trying to understand the closest_point function in qgis. For that, I created a polygon layer with two features, and through the Geometry Generator I intend to find the closest point between those two.

This is the expression I'm using, but it is not working:

```
closest_point(geometry (get_feature_by_id('closest', 1)), geometry(get_feature_by_id ('closest', 2)))
```

Can someone help me to find out why?

[image]

Comment: How is it not working? Please explain what you expect and what happens instead.

Comment: Well, I'm really a beginner in this but I guess it was supposed to draw the point in geometry one closest to geometry two, isn't that right? And that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression should work well, but you have geometry errors in your layer: you have multipart geometries with just one part. That's what the `Check Geometries` tool found.

To solve the problem: run `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Multipart to singleparts` - in the resulting layer, both your original as well as the following expression should work:

```
closest_point(
    geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, 1)), 
    geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, 2))
)
```

`@layer` refers to the current layer.

[image]

Comment: I'm really really sorry. I shared it wrongly. This is the right link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mtkwMYoLzHUV2ViSlmiIFoV4fkhW3OIT?usp=sharing

Comment: How did you identify that it was a multipart? I can only say a feature is a multipart when you try to select it and and both features are selected.

Comment: I used the `Check Geometries` tool. It was the inverse: you had two separate features, but somehow QGIS consiedered them to be multipart, but they consisted both of just one part, thus it was inconsistent.

Comment: Go figure! Well thank you very much, it worked perfectly!!